# setParam says method undefined

Tags: menu-parameters

I'm trying to set one of my menu parameters.  But I'm getting the error

**0 CALL TO UNDEFINED METHOD JOOMLA\CMS\APPLICATION\SITEAPPLICATION::SETPARAMS()**

My code is:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setParams($appParams['pageclass_sfx'],$pageClass);
```

And I see setParams as an option in the API https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Menu.MenuItem.html#method_setParams

I find the API quite difficult to understand without a relevant example.  From searching the CMS code on GitHub I found this example:

```
function setParams($option, $param = false)
{
    return $this->IC->set_parameters($option, $param);
}
```

But that seems to confirm my code is written in the right way.  In any case it seems to be saying the method doesn't exist.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The documentation linked is for `Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem` but you're manipulating `Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication`.

Comment: I want to concatenate something to the page class. I see it in the JFactory get application.

Comment: Where is your code located? In a plugin?

Comment: Yes, in a plugin. Maybe it's the plugin? Should it be onAfterRender or what type should it be? And how can I find out which type to use in the future? For me doing anything after render should work but that's probably wrong

Comment: `onAfterRender` is too late. It's used mainly to manipulate the already generated document. `onAfterRoute` would probably be most suitable in this case.

Comment: Nice, I'll try that. But what's the best way for me to find out more information about which one to use when?

Comment: See documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System.

Comment: Awesome, never seen that before. Such a good writeup. I thought there were more options. It's a great resource thank you.

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes here, I found others https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Plugin/Events

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where this could be set. The app params and the menu item params. Which ones would be used depends on how component is coded. See example how params are handled in article view https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/57ca7a411fbeb3ec0c46594b1d4859c91c0b6a38/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php#L73-L129.

To set a param in app:

```
$this->app->getParams()->set('pageclass_sfx', $pageClass);
```

To set a param for current menu item:

```
if ($menuItem = $this->app->getMenu()->getActive())
{
    $menuItem->params->set('pageclass_sfx', $pageClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be trying to set the parameter through the JApplication object, but instead via the component helper, like so:

```
$menuParams = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_menus');
$menuParams->set('pageclass_sfx', $pageClass);
```

Comment: Ah I see.  But when I do that I get `Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
   'data' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
  )),
   'initialized' => false,
   'separator' => '.',
));` from my var_dump.  Which doesn't include `pageclass_sfx`.

Comment: As a note to myself or others, if it is empty I don't think it is included in the array