# Adding an alias to the body class by appending it to the existing alias

Tags: plugin, plugin-events, system-plugin

I have successfully managed to add the alias to the body class by creating a plugin.  It uses vanilla JS and isn't overly problematic except when I combine and compress my JS it stops working.  I'm not sure why.  But I have always thought it better to achieve this via PHP anyway.

I came up with the below code using `onBeforeCompileHead` instead of `onBeforeRender` as I was trying to work out why it wouldn't work and I assume after the head had been compiiled that would be too late.  Can anyone assist me in understanding why this code doesn't work?

```
<?php
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Alias as body class
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# version 1.0.0
# author Kind of Useful
# copyright Copyright (C) 2019 Kind of Useful. All Rights Reserved.
# @license - http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
# Websites: https://www.kindofuseful.com
# Technical Support: info@kindofuseful.com
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

class plgSystemKouAliasAsBodyClass extends JPlugin
{   
    function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {

        $app            = JFactory::getApplication();

        // If we are on admin don't process.
        if (!$app->isClient('site'))
        {
            return;
        }

        $document       = JFactory::getDocument();
        $menu           = $app->getMenu();
        $active         = $menu->getActive();
        $alias          = ucfirst($active->alias);

        $prefix         = $this->params['prefix'];      

        if ($this->params['class'])                           // getParams and setParams only if something to add
        {
            $pageClass = $app->getParams()['pageclass_sfx'];

            $alias = $prefix . $alias;

            if (!empty($pageClass))                           // isset and not an empty string
            {
                $pageClass .= ' ' . $alias;   // append new class
            }
            else
            {
                $pageClass = $alias;          // declare new class
            }
            $app->setParams($pageClass);
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: [My suggested code amendments](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/joomla-php-how-can-a-plugin-append-a-css-class-to-the-body-section/24004?noredirect=1#comment32459_24004) assumed the variables that you had written were actually holding the expected data (I didn't change any functionality).  Please clarify the data that is available to these variables at runtime by sharing the dumped values.

Comment: I think your `setParam()` method is incorrect there. This should take 2 arguments rather than one. Maybe the answers here will help: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24005/setparam-says-method-undefined

Comment: I agree with Mr. Lodder.  The docs: https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JUser::setParam

Comment: Jeesh I've been trying to find that other question/answer for ages!